# How to use regex in SQL which will find only one row

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, sql-like

I've a table that has 3 rows, I'd like to get only the first row using the like statement. When I use `select value from table where value like '%Motor%%Fans%%9%'` it returns two rows the first one and the second one. How to exclude these rows that has different numeric value before 9?

```
VALUE
Motor Fans Base 9
Motor Fans Base 49
Motor Fans Base 13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `like`.  Just use a space before the final `9` and remove the final `%`:

```
where value like '%Motor%Fans% 9'
```

If you also want to match values that end in 91 or 903, then the final wildcard is appropriate:

```
where value like '%Motor%Fans% 9%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_like()`:

```
where regexp_like(value, 'Motor.*Fans\D*9')
```

Regexp breakdown:

```
Motor         # litteral string "Motor"
.*            # 0 to n characters
Fans          # litteral string "Fans"
\D*           # 0 to n non-digit characters
9             # a litteral "9"
```